# Mapping Tensor Between Two Arbitrary Tensors

Tags: tensors

I am investigating the properties underlying linear transformations between arbitrarily valued tensors.

I wish to prove or disprove this theorem:

Between **any** two ***sets*** of tensors ***A*** and ***B*** there exists a mapping tensor ***M*** such that ***M(A[N]) = B[N]*** where ***N*** is the index in the tensor sets.

For example:

A = [[2], [3]]
B = [[10,6], [15, 9]]

then

M = [[5, 3]]

I am trying to determine that if I were to generate a randomly initialized set of tensors ***A*** and a randomly initialized set of tensors ***B*** that I could derive some single mapping tensor ***M*** that maps all the elements of ***A*** onto ***B***. The dimensions of ***M*** are also arbitrary.

Is this possible? Are there any numerical gotchas that would get in the way?